# How can I find out why a ToolTip is closing in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a strange problem with ToolTips in WPF (.NET 6): My ToolTips are showing only for a few milliseconds and then close again. It was working like normal a while ago, but I can't find out exactly what change to my application has broken the tooltips. At least I can say that I didn't mess with the ShowDuration property.
Is there any possibility how I can find out why a tooltip is closing? I tried to catch the ToolTipClosing event and add a breakpoint, but there doesn't seem to be any helpful information in the ToolTipEventArgs.

Comment: Use `spyxx.exe` (aka _Spy++_) and/or WPF Snoop.exe to inspect the window-messages being sent to the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the .Net6 WPF release: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/6289

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why I didn't find this..

Comment: Not sure. I didn't even run into this issue yet and I've seen at least 4 different issues about it in the core and WPF repos.